# Remove duplicates by match

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Considering having this list:

```
data = ["http://x.com/", "http://x.com/some/dir/", "http://x.com/other", "http://y.com/something", "http://y.com/else"]
```

I want to remove duplicates that are matched so expected output is:

```
http://x.com/
http://y.com/something
```

I know about `list(set(data))` trick but it wouldn't work for this case.

I thought of iterating and making it in dict as key : value form so domain is key and value is the whole url and only take one occurance but I think that technique is crappy and not pythonic.

Comment: How do you define duplicate, do you do it by the primary domain address?

Comment: How is `"http://x.com/some/dir/"` a duplicate of `"http://x.com/"` and why would `"http://y.com/something"` be preferred over `"http://y.com/else"`? Do you simply want the first occurrance of a URL for any domain in the list?

Comment: @SimasJoneliunas Yes

Comment: @Grismar Yes I only want first occurrence of url by domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gets you one entry per domain (happens to be the last, not the first):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

data = ["http://x.com/", "http://x.com/some/dir/", "http://x.com/other", "http://y.com/something", "http://y.com/else"]

result = list({urlparse(url).netloc: url for url in data}.values())
```

If you prefer the first:

```
result = list({urlparse(url).netloc: url for url in reversed(data)}.values())
print(result)
```

Outcome:

```
['http://y.com/something', 'http://x.com/']
```

This works as follows:

- `urlparse('https://somedomain.com/some/path')` will break down the URL and one of the parts `.netloc` is the domain you're after, i.e. `'somedomain.com'`
- `{urlparse(url).netloc: url for url in reversed(data)}` reverses the list `data` and then for each `url` in the list, it gets the domain and adds an entry to a dictionary that's being constructed with the domain as the key and the URL as the value; since keys in a dictionary have to be unique, every type the same domain comes up, the entry is overwritten (hence the reversal)
- `list(somedict.values())` just takes the values of the dictionary and turns them into a simple list.

So, that explains how `result = list({urlparse(url).netloc: url for url in data}.values())` results in the same as `result = ['http://y.com/something', 'http://x.com/']` for your input `data`.

Comment: How dictionary keys can't be duplicated?